# Latexmk Not Rendering After First Page

Tags: multicol, parskip, newspaper

We're using LaTeX to turn [reddit into an eBook](http://news.d8u.us/). It isn't rendering anything beyond the first page. A sample of my LaTeX source is below -- as it's dynamically-generated, the failures are intermittent:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdftitle={The Reddit Times},pdfnewwindow,frenchlinks=true]{hyperref}

\date{\DTMNow  PST8PDT}
\currentvolume{0}
\currentissue{0}
\SetPaperName{Reddit Times}
\SetHeaderName{Reddit Times}
\SetPaperSlogan{Bitcoin Wallet 1BAi7NrABpbUy74x-t5KKPt3JSjgdLumksh}
\SetPaperLocation{by reddit2pdf}
\SetPaperPrice{0.72 \MakeTextLowercase{m}BTC }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{3}{
\byline{\href{http://www.dailywire.com/news/15163/ben-carson-finds-500-billion-billion-errors-during-joseph-curl}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Ben Carson Finds $500 Billion In Errors During Audit Of Obama HUD}}}}{lurk3295}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://thinkpol.ca/2017/04/04/customers-abandon-cibc-after-bank-axes-canadian-workers-and-ships-jobs-to-india/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Customers abandon CIBC after bank axes Canadian workers and ships jobs to India}}}}{Former\_PM\_Harper}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://www.washingtonpost.com/powerpost/senate-poised-for-historic-clash-over-supreme-court-nominee-neil-gorsuch/2017/04/06/40295376-1aba-11e7-855e-4824bbb5d748\_story.html?utm\_term=.a9e79646973b}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Democrats block Gorsuch consideration, paving way for Senate rules change}}}}{cr0128}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.inlander.com/Bloglander/archives/2017/04/05/spokane-judge-cites-trumps-pussy-grabbing-in-decision-on-assault-of-young-woman}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Spokane Judge cites Trumps "pussy grabbing" in decision}}}}{hipmommie}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 14.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/05/business/kendall-jenner-pepsi-ad.html?mwrsm=Reddit}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Pepsi pulls ad accused of trivializing Black Lives Matter}}}}{throwaway1337woman}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://bigstory.ap.org/article/9bb6522fe5c642a38a62bd7f99b23708/girl-found-living-monkeys-indian-forest}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Girl found living with monkeys in Indian forest}}}}{BernadetteSanderson}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/kirtsten-dunst-sex-scenes-filming-trauma-the-beguiled-actress-colin-farrell-a7670711.html}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Kirsten Dunst reveals the trauma of filming sex scenes}}}}{Ekudar}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-39514166}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Hitler colouring book removed by Dutch shop after outrage - BBC News}}}}{Rocky\_Handsom}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.richmond.com/news/virginia/judge-allows-some-of-rolling-stone-s-requests-for-u/article\_afe988e4-c979-5ed4-b152-cb23f2adf91e.html}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Judge allows some of Rolling Stone’s requests for U.Va. fraternity to proceed}}}}{VCUBNFO}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.foxnews.com/us/2017/04/05/astronaut-john-glenn-to-be-interred-at-arlington-cemetery-on-thursday.html}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{John Glenn to be interred at Arlington Cemetery on Thursday.}}}}{MeatnChease}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.miaminewtimes.com/news/charles-kinsey-was-shot-after-a-north-miami-cop-called-halt-it-is-a-toy-9254204}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{New Recording Paints Damning Picture of Cops Who Shot Charles Kinsey}}}}{Boshasaurus\_Rex}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.cbc.ca/news/health/tests-treatments-choosing-wisely-cihi-1.4057702}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Unnecessary care in Canada tops 1 million tests and treatments a year}}}}{EmeraldLight}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/national-spelling-bee-adjusts-its-rules-prevent-ties-180962801/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{The National Spelling Bee Adjusts Its Rules To Prevent Ties: Top spellers will be required to take a written test on the final evening of the competition}}}}{beemdi}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://host.madison.com/wsj/news/local/crime/janesville-schools-in-lockdown-because-of-gun-theft-police-say/article\_ec237d02-c7ba-5b55-9488-6da6ef86c671.html}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Janesville WI schools in lockdown because of gun theft, police say}}}}{Norn-Iron}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Report-Second-Syrian-village-hit-by-chemical-attack-this-week-486277}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Reports of a Second Gas Attack in Syria}}}}{sven0341}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-04-06/stargazing-live-four-planets-discovered-in-new-solar-system/8423142}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Stargazing Live viewers find four-planet solar system via crowd-sourcing project}}}}{OtherWisdom}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://deadline.com/2017/04/wga-sends-strike-warning-letter-to-ad-buyers-as-upfronts-loom-1202062086/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Writers Guild of America sends warning letter to TV ad buyers about possible guild strike action against networks/studios}}}}{dynamicsearchguy}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-economy-idUSKBN1781JE?il=0}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{U.S. weekly jobless claims post largest drop in almost two years}}}}{Trumpologist}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 18.0 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://time.com/4727871/human-papillomavirus-hpv-sti/?xid=time\_socialflow\_twitter}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Almost Half of U.S. Adults Have HPV}}}}{NinjaDiscoJesus}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/us/man-gives-portland-mayor-a-pepsi-during-tense-moment/ar-BBzsCgm?li=BBmkt5R\&ocid=spartanntp}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Man gives Portland mayor a Pepsi during tense moment at city council meeting}}}}{Frago242}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 5.56 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://www.readfrontier.org/stories/security-guard-accidentally-shot-weekend-wanenmachers-tulsa-arms-show/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Security guard accidentally shot over the weekend at 'Wanenmacher's Tulsa Gun Show'}}}}{tburns1469}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{http://bigstory.ap.org/article/17d3a6851f234f458c1e868ba39a9d1c/report-murder-suspect-was-upset-pregnant-girlfriend-smoked}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Report: Murder suspect was upset pregnant girlfriend smoked}}}}{einsteinshadow}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://www.thecollegefix.com/post/32003/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Mizzou enrollment plunge continues: Three more dorms shutting down next year}}}}{flashlightbulb}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 0.22 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/news+ )\linebreak[4] Click the headline to open the piece
\closearticle
\closearticle
}\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

An example of a TeX file that does render follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdftitle={The Reddit Times},pdfnewwindow,frenchlinks=true]{hyperref}

\date{\DTMNow  PST8PDT}
\currentvolume{0}
\currentissue{0}
\SetPaperName{Reddit Times}
\SetHeaderName{Reddit Times}
\SetPaperSlogan{Bitcoin Wallet 1BAi7NrABpbUy74x-t5KKPt3JSjgdLumksh}
\SetPaperLocation{by reddit2pdf}
\SetPaperPrice{0.72 \MakeTextLowercase{m}BTC }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{3}{
\byline{\href{https://www.reddit.com/r/MyTheoryIs/comments/62i864/theory\_of\_god/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{theory of god}}}}{20556}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 13667.56 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/MyTheoryIs+ )\linebreak[4] My concept is that God is time and our existence. There have been theories about our infinity wide universe being surrounded by an infinite amount of bubbles filled with other infinite universes. My theory is that eventually on judgement day as the Christians believe, that God will make us all one. The bible says God will choose the lambs while others try to pretend to be a sheep. This means that the most holy people will be picked to become one person. I believe that God will make us all one in order to make us God so that he can sacrifice himself against the greatest evil anywhere ever. And he will die but we will be the new perfect God, and finally we will become different people again and live in perfect peace in heaven, but God would have died. I believe God would have specially chosen one person to be the new God when he's gone and that the new God will have to resurrect him and we will all live together without any God as one and equal because we will have no need for a God without any evil and there will also be no new evil because there will be nothing to complain about when we are all finally equal. If you agree with this theory or even somewhat believe it please spread the word along because I truthfully believe that this is how life is supposed to be. 
\closearticle
\byline{\href{https://www.reddit.com/r/MyTheoryIs/comments/60x2fq/theory\_of\_life\_n\_afterlife/}{\textit{\LARGE \capitalisewords{Theory of Life n after-life}}}}{vishvk}
\footnotesize Estimated Reading time: 882.0 seconds \\ 
( \verb+r/MyTheoryIs+ )\linebreak[4] What if after we die, our souls go back in time(dimension) to be born again as the same baby...and the cycle keeps on n on? ...OR...our souls can jump in time to live a different life in a different era ? But the number and path of lives in continuum is constant. I mean souls are time travellers...
\closearticle}\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: This will generate not 500 billion in errors, but an error: `Carson Finds $500 Billion In Errors`. You must escape various special characters, including `$` (use: `\$`).

Comment: Hm... I've fixed that problem, but it's still not doing so -- is there a comprehensive list of special characters that should be escaped?

Comment: It compiled fine for me earlier today once I fixed the `$` (about to call it a late night). But the absolutely indispensible guide is [this one](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en). In one of the early pages, it goes through the special characters (which are #, $, %, &, _, {, }; but also some others matter for accents and so forth, like ^ and ~).